# Where does Dietlibc define function _start?

Tags: c, libc

I'm successfully doing some prototyping using dietlibc.

For linking, I need function `_start` as entry point, and I'm currently using the one of newlib that is in `crt0.o` [1].

Where can I find the function `_start` of dietlibc?

[1] `/usr/lib/newlib/i486-linux-gnu/lib/crt0.o` from Debian package dietlibc-dev

Answer (score 0):

In Dietlibc, function `_start` is compiled and distributed in a file called `start.o`, not in `crtX.o`.

On my system, it is in `/usr/lib/diet/lib/start.o`.